# How do I resize a specific cell for CollectionView on rotation?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The end result is to have the cell.title and cell.description resize once the device is rotated so that it fills the entire screen. This collectionviewcontroller is within a Viewcontroller so I need a solution that is cell specific.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


  if(collectionView == collection1)
  {


SliderCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"articleCellslider1"
                                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *item = [_articleListslider objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

// set the article image
[cell.image setImageWithURL:[item objectForKey:@"image"]];

// set the text of title UILabel
cell.title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n", [item objectForKey:@"title"]];
cell.title.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0f/255.0f green:74.0f/255.0f blue:146.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
cell.title.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5f];

// set the text of summary UILabel
cell.description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", [item objectForKey:@"description"]];
cell.description.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14];
cell.description.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:0.5f];

cell.targetURL = [item objectForKey:@"link"];

cell.sliderphoto = [item objectForKey:@"sliderphoto"];

cell.date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n", [item objectForKey:@"pubDate"]];

cell.category.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n", [item objectForKey:@"category"]];


return cell;

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Slider" sender:indexPath];



}
```

The cells I want specifically resized on rotation is cell.title and cell.description

Answer (score 1):

Override one of the rotation UIviewController delegate methods, try willRotateToInterfaceOrientation (Probably did instead of will is better) Then when you catch it, reload your table view and set some flag to know that it is rotated.

Then implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: 
(Change size here according to orientation)